# Forecasting in ARIMA (python)

Tags: python, forecasting, arima

I have a time-series data (Date and Total). This is actual data from the past 2 years.

I understand how to pick the (p, q, d) order for ARIMA. And I can divide my data into train and test, and the Arima model models the test data pretty well.

```
history = [x for x in train]
X = writes
predictions = list()
for t in range(len(test)):
    model = ARIMA(history, order=(5,1,0))
    model_fit = model.fit()
    output = model_fit.forecast()
    yhat = output[0]
    predictions.append(yhat)
    obs = test[t]
    history.append(obs)
```

If I plot the predictions with the original data, it matches up to the test portion of the data.

What I would like to have is to extend the forecast out by a year. So, after the above loop, I wrote:

```
forcast = model_fit.forecast(365)
```

But most of the values in forecast are the same. My data is definitely not a straight line.

How do I determine the forecast?